# GET Facebook Search 500 (Internal Server Error) (Laravel 4.1)

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, laravel-4

I am trying to implement a Facebook search on my page (typing up search terms will return Facebook data), but I am running into trouble.  When I type in the search bar, I receive:

```
GET http://url.com/search/facebook?term=mi 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

Where "mi" is the term typed in to search.

Putting this url in a browser yields:

```
file_get_contents(https://graph.facebook.com/search?access_token=&amp;q=mi&amp;type=page): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
```

To break it down, I have a SearchController.php that I am calling with the route:

```
Route::get('/search/facebook', array('uses' => 'SearchController@get_facebook'));
```

get_facebook looks like this:

```
public function get_facebook() {

        //get facebook sdk
        $this->facebook = $this->getFacebook('facebook');

        //set facebook access token
        $this->facebook->accessToken = isset($_SESSION['fb_access_token']) ? $_SESSION['fb_access_token'] : '';        

        $data = $this->facebook->search($_REQUEST['term'], 'page');

        $response = array();
        if(isset($data['data']) && !empty($data['data'])) {
            foreach($data['data'] as $result) {
                if($result['category'] == 'Musician/band' || $result['category'] == 'Artist') {
                    $response[] = $result;
                }
            }
        }

        if(isset($response) && !empty($response)) {
            $this->aasort($response, 'name');
            return Response::json($response);
        } else {
            return Response::json(array());
        }        
    }

public function aasort(&$array, $key) {
        $sorter=array();
        $ret=array();
        reset($array);
        foreach ($array as $ii => $va) {
            $sorter[$ii]=$va[$key];
        }
        asort($sorter);
        foreach ($sorter as $ii => $va) {
            $ret[$ii]=$array[$ii];
        }
        $array=$ret;
    }  

    public function getFacebook($provider) {        
        if($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] != 'url.com') {
            return OAuth2::provider($provider, array('id' => '*********', 'secret' => '************'));
        } else {
            return OAuth2::provider($provider, array('id' => '********', 'secret' => '************'));
        }        
    }
```

For Facebook Authentication I am using the MadewithLove Oauth2 Package for Laravel.

The search function in Facebook.php there looks like this (this is where the error is pointing):

```
public function search($query = '', $type = '') {
        $url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/search?access_token='.$this->accessToken.'&q='.str_replace(' ', '+', $query).'&type='.$type;
        return json_decode(file_get_contents($url), true);
    }
```

Any ideas what is happening here?  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might have something to do with the type of search you're triggering via your functions. According to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api#search you need different types of Access Token depending on the type of your search.

> All Graph API search queries require an access token included in the
>   request. The type of access token you need depends on the type of
>   search you're executing.
>
> Searches across Page and Place objects requires an app access token.
>   All other endpoints require a user access token.

I can't see that distinction in your code.

Comment: Is this a recent a change?  I hadn't been receiving this error up until recently.

Comment: Also, how do I get a specific access token for one of these entities (pages specifically)?